# MIP SDK and AD RMS error "MSIS9622: Client authentication failed"

Tags: c#, microsoft-information-protection, azure-information-protection, mip-sdk

I have followed the AD RMS and MIP SDK tutorials and have set up a environment with AD RMS, ADFS

Here are some snippets from my code:

```
var engineSettings = new FileEngineSettings("internal\\sysadmin", authDelegate, "", "en-US");
engineSettings.Identity = new Identity("internal\\sysadmin");
engineSettings.ProtectionCloudEndpointBaseUrl = "https://adrms.server.com";
engineSettings.ProtectionOnlyEngine = true;
var fileEngine = Task.Run(async () => await fileProfile.AddEngineAsync(engineSettings)).Result;

...snip...

var fileHandlerResult = Task.Run(async () => await fileHandler.CommitAsync(protectedFilePath)).Result;
```

At the CommitAsync line the user is redirected to the ADFS login page and they log in - they then get redirected to an "Authentication Failed" page which says:

```
Error details: error access_denied error_description: MSIS9622: Client authentication failed. Please verify the credential provided for client authentication is valid.
```

Are there additional changes that need to be made to the MIP SDK samples to get them to work with ADFS? Here is a snippet from my AuthDelegateImplementation

```
public string AcquireToken(Identity identity, string authority, string resource, string claims)
        {
            _app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_appInfo.ApplicationId)
                .WithAdfsAuthority("https://adfs.server.com/adfs/", false)
                .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost:50069")
                .Build();

            var accounts = _app.GetAccountsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            // Append .default to the resource passed in to AcquireToken().
            string[] scopes = { resource[^1].Equals('/') ? $"{resource}.default" : $"{resource}/.default" };

            var result = _app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                .WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                .ExecuteAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false)
                .GetAwaiter()
                .GetResult();

            return result.AccessToken;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked my AD FS event viewer logs and I saw that the user did not have permission to access the api.rms.rest.com relying party trust - fixed by editing the access control policy to permit everyone.